# LeetCode 1416 Restore The Array

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem ([Restore  The Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/restore-the-array/)), and I have gotten close but for some reason can't pass the 83th test which is a big string. I have also saw a very similar solution that did pass everything, So I'll put it here too.

> my code:

```c
    #define MOD 1000000007

    int kLength;
    int* mem;

    int dp(char* s, int length, int k, int i, int prevNum);
    int numLength(int n);

    int numberOfArrays(char* s, int k) {
        int result;
        int length = strlen(s);


        kLength = numLength(k);

        mem = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
        memset(mem, -1, sizeof(int) * length);
    
        result = dp(s, length, k, 0, -1);

        free(mem);

        return result;
    }

    int dp(char* s, int length, int k, int i, int prevNum) {
        int posLength;
        int result, num;
        char* numS = NULL;

        if (i == length) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (mem[i] != -1) {
            return mem[i] % MOD;
        }

        result = 0;

        for (posLength = 1; s[i] != '0' && posLength <= kLength && posLength <= length - i; posLength++) {
            numS = (char*) malloc(posLength + 1);
            memcpy(numS, s + i, posLength);
            numS[posLength] = '\0';

            num = atoi(numS);
            free(numS);

            if (num < 1 || num > k) {
                break;
            }

            result += dp(s, length, k, i + posLength, num) % MOD;
            result %= MOD;
        }

        result %= MOD;

        return mem[i] = result % MOD;
    }

    int numLength(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + numLength(n / 10);
    }
```

> The similar working code:

```c
class Solution {
public:
    int MOD = 1000000007;
    int solve(string& s, int& k, vector<int>&dp, int startIdx)
    {
        if (startIdx == s.size()) return 1;
        
        if (dp[startIdx] != -1) return dp[startIdx]; //retrieve results
        long long currNum = 0, ways = 0;
        //=================================================
        for (int i = startIdx; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            int currDig = s[i] - '0';
            currNum = (currNum * 10) + currDig; //building the number from L->R

            if (currNum < 1 || currNum > k) break;
            int nextWays = solve(s, k, dp, i + 1);
            ways = (ways +  nextWays) % MOD;
        }
        //====================================================
        return dp[startIdx] = ways; //store results
    }
    int numberOfArrays(string s, int k) 
    {
        vector<int>dp(s.size(), -1);
        int ans = solve(s, k, dp, 0);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

[This is the test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhjkZ.png)

If someone can help me understand the logical difference between the 2 codes, and why my code doesn't pass the tests I'll grateful.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: This is insane:  `#define MOD (int) (pow(10, 9) + 7)`  Not only does it risk floating point errors (some implementations will give the wrong integer result), but it's also calling `pow` every single time you execute it.  Change it to `1000000007`, or at least some constant expression.  Or store it in a variable.  And make sure the value is correct, and not some roundoff error value like `1000000006`, which it will be with some math libraries.  Note that the working code correctly uses `1000000007`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude lol let's see you debug it with that input, I'm trying to ask if someone can see what's the logical difference between the 2, I'm not asking anyone to debug for me.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for the tip, I'm pretty sure pow() has O(1) time complexity so it's not that expensive. But anyway the output is the same when I change it to 1000000007.

Comment: @SagiSason Just because it's O(1) doesn't mean it's not expensive.